# Can't Install libffi-devel in centos 7

Tags: python, centos7, yum

`yum install libffi-devel` is not working in centos 7 OS.

I have a chatbot application(python3) in the centos 7 server which requires many libraries to be installed. At some point i faced the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'`

My default `python --version` is 3.6.8
`python3 --version` is 3.7.11
since my default python version is python3, i configured the usr/bin/yum file to use python2(default centos python version) for yum to work.

i am using python 3.7 for my application. Any help will be greatly appreciated. TIA.